# How do I block access to certain URLs in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, drupal

I have a `Drupal` site where new content is added very rarely. Recently, there have been an increasing number of visits from bots to various URLs (node/add, user/register), which return `Drupal's` "Access denied" page.

I want to block access to these *URLs* in `.htaccess`. I have tried the following and it works:

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
  Redirect 403 /node/add
  Redirect 403 /user/register
</IfModule>
```

However, bots can still access `?q=node/add and ?q=user/register`. I have tried including `?q=` in the code above but no success.

How do I block access to these *URLs* in `.htaccess` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `mod_rewrite` to do url-manipulation based on the query string. You'll need something like the (untested) code below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(node/add|user/register)$
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

What does this do? It matches any url (`^`), then checks if the query string is equal to `q=node/add` or `q=user/register`. If either one matches, then the url is not rewritten (`-`), but access is denied `[F]` and the rewriting stops for this iteration `[L]`.

Answer (score 2):

While doing this via .htaccess is completely viable, I would reconsider this approach and consider putting these URLs into robots.txt for crawler bots. This way, they will ignore them completely, which is definitely more healthy for SEO.

Also, you can use Global Redirect module (https://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) to ensure that only clean URLs are used.

Comment: m1n0, thank you for your reply. The URLs are there in robots.txt but I suppose the visits have been from spam bots and not from crawler bots. I didn't know the Global Redirect module, I'll try it out.